# How to login without running script in /etc/profile.d

Tags: linux, ssh, login

I mistakenly put a sh script in /etc/profile.d to automatically run some commands after login.
the first of the script is running

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo su - userb
several normal commands
```

However when I login as "usera", then running the script, it required to enter userb password for the next command running. 
The problem is I don't have userb password, I have tried ctrl-c and input incorrect password few times, they caused direct session end. ctrl-z is also not working

Is that possible to not run the script or get back to "usera" so that I can manually remove the script?

Comment: sudo asks for the password of usera, not the password of userb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log in by specifying bash with the `--noprofile` parameter.

From [the documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> **--noprofile**
>   Do not read either the system-wide startup file /etc/profile or any of the personal initialization files ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, or ~/.profile. By default, bash reads these files when it is invoked as a login shell (see INVOCATION below).

To use this:

```
ssh usera@yourserver bash --noprofile
```

Don't be alarmed if this doesn't seem to work, if the login succeeds you'll get nothing, not even a prompt (this is all set by login scripts). But you can use the  server as usual.

Comment: Many thanks! I tried two ways below, but userb password is still needed, do you see the issue?
1. Putty-Connection-SSH-Remote command:ssh usera@serverIP bash --noprofile
2. Putty-Connection-SSH-Remote command:/bin/bash --noprofile

Comment: I don't see any way to do this with PuTTY. Looks like you need a different ssh client. I used this with the openssh client from the Windows Linux Subsystem.